# While loop not working unless I insert a print statement - java

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a GUI for a program which allows a user to accept or decline a request send to a listening server socket. I do this by using a `DoYouAcceptWindow` and another bit of code which opens it.

The code in `DoYouAcceptWindow.java` is as follows

```java
public class DoYouAcceptWindow extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
    private short d = 0;
    private JButton accept;

    public DoYouAcceptWindow() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        accept = new JButton("Accept");
        accept.addMouseListener(this);
        add(accept);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public short getDecided() {
        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(accept)) {
            System.out.println("Accepted");
            d = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

(I have remove a lot of unnecessary functions from this as well as the ability to decline the request just to make it easier to read)

And the code that uses the above class:

```java
while (true) {
    DoYouAcceptWindow w = new DoYouAcceptWindow();
    short decided = w.getDecided();
    while (decided == 0) {
        decided = w.getDecided();
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
    w.dispose();
    if (w.getDecided() == 2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

(This code has also had a lot of unnecessary parts removed)

When you press the button, it prints "accepted" like it should (and I assume it sets d = 1 or 2). However, it does not break out of the while loop. When I add a print statement into the while loop however (like this):

```java
while (decided == 0) {
    decided = w.getDecided();
    System.out.println(0);
}
```

It fixes itself. If I run it in debug mode (in eclipse), it fixes itself. Why does it not break out of the while loop without the print statement? And how can I fix it? (without adding a print statement)

Comment: Do a clean of your build directories and rebuild the project. It might be a cache problem.

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere: no, it has *nothing* to do with that. JFrame is not modal and you need to use a modal JDialog to block program flow for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say for sure, but with the description this could be a memory visibility issue.

Could you try declaring the value volatile?

```
private volatile short d = 0;
```

Comment: I disagree. He's accessing a variable that is changed by another thread without any synchronization. And this is typically an production-only issue as the JRE in server mode optimizes more than when you're just debugging. It may be something else, but since it's only a single keyword I would give it a try anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that a JFrame is non-modal, meaning it does not block the calling code's program flow, and so your while loop will repeat forever, blocking the Swing event thread, and rendering your application useless.

One solution is to use a modal dialog such as a modal JDialog or a JOptionPane (which really is a modal JDialog in disguise).

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class DoYouAcceptEg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int response = JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION;
        while (response != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION && response != JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you accept?", 
                    "Accept?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("Accepted");
            } else if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("Rejected");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Undecided");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So why does the print statement allow it to run properly?

Comment: @LightningdeGolem: It likely slows down a tight loop enough to allow the Swing event thread to run and display the GUI. Regardless, that tight loop is not appropriate for an event-driven program.

Comment: What’s a modal?